# Apache Kafka spout is not working on Consumer Side

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to integrate MongoDB and Storm-Kafka, Kafka Producer produces data from MongoDB but it fails to fetch from Consumer side.

Kafka version :0.10.*
Storm version :1.2.1

Do i need to add any functionality in Consumer?

Comment: No one is going to be able to answer this unless you post some more details. A good start would be posting your topology wiring, and any bits of your supervisor, NImbus and worker logs that look like they might be relevant.

Comment: Hi  @StigRohdeDøssing,    Please find the code snippet at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000556/kafka-consumer-is-very-slow-to-consume-data-and-only-consuming-first-500-records