# Kafka consumer is very slow to consume data and only consuming first 500 records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to integrate MongoDB and Storm-Kafka, Kafka Producer produces data from MongoDB but it fails to fetch all records from Consumer side. It only consuming 500-600 records out of 1 million records.

There are no errors in log file, topology is still alive but not processing further records.

Kafka version :0.10.* Storm version :1.2.1

Do i need to add any configs in Consumer?

```
 conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_BACKPRESSURE_ENABLE, false);
 conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 2048);
 conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE, 16384);
 conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_SEND_BUFFER_SIZE, 16384);

BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(zookeeperUrl);
        SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, topic, zkRoot, consumerGroupId);
        spoutConfig.scheme = new KeyValueSchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringKeyValueScheme());
        spoutConfig.fetchSizeBytes = 25000000;
        if (startFromBeginning) {
            spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = OffsetRequest.EarliestTime();
        } else {
            spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = OffsetRequest.LatestTime();
        }
        return new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
    }
```

I want Kafka spout should read all records from kafka topic which are produced by producer.

Comment: What happens if you set max spout pending to something larger (e.g. 10k)?

Comment: I think the first step to debugging this should be that you remove all parts of your topology, except for a logging bolt. That way, we can determine whether the issue is with the spout or your topology.

Comment: Also I'd strongly urge you to swap to the spout in `storm-kafka-client`, rather than using the one in `storm-kafka`. The one in `storm-kafka` will prevent you from upgrading to Kafka 2.x.